# Can't open Arena Reports, error says Excel is not installed

Tags: excel, arena-simulation

I am starting to learn this software for a class and every time I try to open a report, this message shows up:
[Error when I finish running a simulation and try to see the results report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TayUJ.png)

I do have Excel installed in my computer and I can manually open the .xlsm file (excel macro-enabled file) it creates for the report, is there a way to fix this?

I have tried editing permissions for excel macros and googling the error, I couldn't find anything helpful.